# Mapping in excel using python

Tags: python

Excel 1

```
Group Summary Label     Amount

Individual Member
Family Member
Family
```

Excel 2

```
Network Label       Value

Individual Member   100
Family Member       200
Family              300
```

I have two Excel sheets and I am trying to map values. As you see both excels has different column names but rows are same. I am trying to map 'value' in excel 2 to Amount in excel 1

I am expecting result like this. How can I do this using Python? I am new and trying to learn.

```
Group Summary Label     Amount

Individual Member       100
Family Member           200
Family                  300
```

Comment: This is not hard, right?  You can read the second Excel sheet in using one of the Excel modules, and create a dict that maps the label to a value.  Now, you just copy rows from the first sheet to the new sheet, looking up the group name and filling in the amount.

Answer (score 0):

First, open two dataframe of each sheet inside the excel:

```
df = pd.ExcelFile('excelfilename.xls')
df1 = pd.read_excel(df, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(df, 'Sheet2')
```

now you can match the two dataFrames into one

```
df1.drop(["Amount"], axis=1)
df2 = df2.join(df1)
df2 = df2.rename(columns={"Value": "Amount"}, errors="raise")
```